# my web application stop working automatically after some time on iis 6

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis

i am new in .net technology

My web service is hosted on iis 6 and it stop working automatically after sometime may be 4 or 6 hour(2 or 3 time in a day) and after restart application pool web service work fine. i don't know where is problem please help!

Comment: Define 'stop working'

Comment: Check the event log and see if you can find the error. To see the event viewer. Go to Run and type 'eventvwr'

Answer (score 0):

In the IIS 6 Recycling Worker Processes  is available only when IIS is running in worker process isolation mode.
Kinldly go through the link below
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2a231dcb-d786-4b6d-b3ba-bda04061a5e7.mspx?mfr=true